# Issue integrating inside ode45 loop

Tags: matlab, ode, numerical-integration

When I try to use this Matlab code it goes in an infinite loop. I am trying to perform integration inside `ode45`:

```
clear
clc
options = odeset('RelTol',1e-4,'AbsTol',[1e-4 1e-4 1e-5]);
[T,Y] = ode45(@rigid,[0 12],[0 1 1],options);

plot(T,Y(:,1),'+',T,Y(:,2),'*',T,Y(:,3),'.')


function dy = rigid(t,y)
dy = zeros(3,1);    % a column vector

dy(1) = y(2) ;

dy(2) = -y(1) * y(3);
fun = @(t) exp(-t.^2).*log(t).^2+y(1);
q = integral(fun,0,Inf);
dy(3) = y(2) * y(3) + q;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "infinite loop." Your function just takes a very long time to integrate. Try setting `tspan` to `[0 1e-7]`. It appears to be a high frequency oscillation, but I don't know if your equations are correct (that's a math question rather than a programming one). Such systems are hard to integrate accurately (`ode15` might be a better choice), let alone quickly.

You also didn't bother to mention the important fact that the call to `integral` is generating a warning message:

```
Warning: Minimum step size reached near x = 1.75484e+22. There may be a
singularity, or the tolerances may be too tight for this problem. 
> In funfun/private/integralCalc>checkSpacing at 457
  In funfun/private/integralCalc>iterateScalarValued at 320
  In funfun/private/integralCalc>vadapt at 133
  In funfun/private/integralCalc at 84
  In integral at 88
  In rtest1>rigid at 17
  In ode15s at 580
  In rtest1 at 5
```

Printing out warning messages on each iteration greatly slows down integration. There's a good reason for this warning. You do realize that the function that you're evaluating with `integral` from `0` to `Inf` is equivalent to the following, right?

```
sqrt(pi)*((eulergamma + log(4))^2/8 + pi^2/16) + Inf*y(1)
```

where `eulergamma` is `psi(1)` or `double(sym('eulergamma'))`. Your integrand doesn't converge.

If you like, can try to avoid the warning message in one of two ways.

**1.** Turn off the the warning (being sure to re-enable it afterwards). You can do that with the following code:

```
...
warning('OFF','MATLAB:integral:MinStepSize');
[T,Y] = ode45(@rigid,[0 12],[0 1 1],options);
warning('ON','MATLAB:integral:MinStepSize');
...
```

You can obtain the the ID for a waring via the `lastwarn` function.

**2.** The other option might be to change your integration bounds and avoid the warning altogether, e.g.:

```
...
q = integral(fun,0,1e20);
...
```

This may or may not be acceptable, but `integral` is not be returning the correct solution either because the result doesn't converge.